# Do Android devices have a static IP address?

Tags: android, ip

Do Android devices have a single static IP address that a server could identify them? Im wondering simce that would allow my game to save data without needing a login.

Comment: I don't know about IP, but they should have a unique mac address.

Comment: Consider what happens when the user replaces/upgrades the device, and restores data from a backup or SD card. Should that new device be considered to be from the same user? If so, then you probably don't want to be tied to any attribute of the hardware or network configuration.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This depends entirely on what they are connected to.  By default, no.  Most Android devices are configured for DHCP for wireless networks and I don't know of any carriers that assign static IP addresses to mobile devices on their data networks.

Comment: I've been looking for a way to fix my Android mobile IP, via some kind of proxy or IP spoofer or something, but to no avail so far. I'm trying to secure remote access to my router from only a single IP, and I can't do this reliably if my IP changes all the time. There doesn't seem to be anything useful on the Play store at least. If I find something I'll post back.

Answer (score 9):

As other people have already answered, no, mobile devices generally don't have a static IP address and instead use DHCP to get a dynamic IP address.

However, to answer your base question, you can generate a unique token for the user using the [java.util.UUID class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html). Save this generated token to your app's SharedPreferences and you can use it to identify your users:

```
public static String getDeviceUuid(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    // Attempt to get an existing device uuid
    String uuid = preferences.getString("device_uuid_key", "");
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(uuid)) {
        // We don't have a device id, generate one!
        uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        // Persist the new id to shared preferences
        final Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("device_uuid_key", uuid);
        editor.commit();
    }
    return uuid;
}
```

Comment: What about a change of device? Wouldn't this alter the token

Comment: Yes, that would alter the token. Also, if they uninstall the app, then reinstall it, they would get a new token. If you want to identify them across these changes you'll need to ultimately associate the token with a user account (an email address or username). That way they can log in to the account when they reinstall your app or change devices.

Answer (score 6):

An Android device can both be connected via WiFi, and 3G, which obviously has different IPs.
The IP address on 3G will also change every time it reconnects.

Answer (score 1):

The mobile operators uses DHCP (Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol) is an application layer protocol which is used to assign an IP address to the devices which are connected to its network newly and also assigns reusable IP addresses to the mobile devices.

Answer (score -3):

In 2023 there are 2 ways to have a public static IP address on your phone:

1. Pay a VPN service and install VPN software adapters in your phone that will use your LTE/5G wireless connection. Beware that you have bandwidth and data limitation. Any server you might setup on your phone will suffer from those limitations. VPN's providers in fact will not allocate all their bandwidth to your phone.
2. Rent a public static IP address from your ISP. Configure the WiFi interface of your fiber optic home router to assign the public IP address to your phone using the MAC address of your phone's WiFi interface. Dig into your phone to retrieve that MAC address.
   In this case the only limitation you have is the WiFi bandwidth.

Important:

There's no way to assign a public static IP address to any phone using a wired USB-C to Ethernet adapter. Smartphone's operating systems just don't allow that.

The USB-C to Ethernet adapter can only be used to share the LTE/5G connection of your phone with other hosts on the same LAN. In this case the phone acts as a wired router and this whole thing is automatically managed by the operating system.

Please note the following point:

Tech giants just don't want us programmers to use our mobile phones as small power-frugal PC's or worst yet as data servers.

They rule the Internet.

Comment: That's not a thing that "tech giants" decide